# Cómo tirar datos gps (csv) sobre un mapa con OpenStreetMap, en Python?

Tags: python, google-maps, gps

Estoy haciendo el trabajo de final de carrera y estudio la movilidad humana dónde dispongo de las coordenadas gps (latitud y longitud) de un grupo de estudiantes cuando van a la escuela.

Mi tutor me ha dicho que lo primero que tengo que hacer es tirar las trayectorias sobre el mapa para poder analizar bien los puntos y limpiar los datos. Me ha dicho que use Python y tire los datos sobre OpenStreetMap.

Soy un poco nuevo em python y en la programacion y investigando he conseguido tirar las trayectorias sobre un mapa del barrio/distrito de la ciudad dónde se encuentra la escuela. El problema es que necesito una visión ampliada en la zona dónde hay los datos para poder diferenciar bien los puntos de la trayectoria y las calles, etc. Por lo tanto, lo que necesito es:

1- Ampliar la zona dónde proyecto los datos
2- Que el mapa se vea cómo googlemaps, con las calles, etc.

Investigando he encontrado que tengo que usar una "bouding box" para graficar los limites del mapa que me interesan y para el punto 2 le tengo que ir añadiendo las capas con las calles, etc. Pero no lo logro la manera de hacerlo y no lo veo por ningún sitio.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea me seria de gran ayuda, les dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora y la imagen que he logrado. Muchas gracias

```
python

import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from time import time

%matplotlib inline


place_name='Sants-Montjuïc, Barcelona, Spain' 
graph=ox.graph_from_place(place_name)  
type(graph)


nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)   
nodes.head()
edges.head()
type(edges)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15)) #plotejem el mapa
edges.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, edgecolor='#BC8F8F')  #eixos


df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\1-MON.csv')
crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}
df.head()

geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip( df["longitude"], df["latitude"])]

geo_df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)   
geo_df.head()
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, marker='o',markersize=2, color="blue")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden